# XAMPP intl problem on mac Catalina version10.15.1

Tags: php, macos, cakephp-3.0

I have tried installing using pecl command but still getting the same issue. Enabled the extension in the php.ini but again of new use

> Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php70-intl/7.0.27_24/intl.so'

I am trying to install CakePHP. PHP version is 7.2 and intl present on mac /usr/local/Cellar/php70-intl . Please help me with the same. I have tried almost everything.

> brew install icu4c 
>   root$: sudo pecl update-channels 
>   root$: sudo pecl install intl

tried everything mentioned above but still of no use